# Using display: flex in older iOS Safari possible?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

iOS Safari 8.1:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbmsanfv9pyj2vv/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2015.50.15.png?dl=0

vertical alignment issues in the top, how to solve this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/svlcld0l5vj0uj6/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2015.51.19.png?dl=0

Google Maps not showing up,
Footer not breaking up

---

Versus

iOS Safari 9.2 (everything works)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3ua5w3i2xzumfy/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2015.53.45.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/spvmoll707sl78o/Screenshot%202016-02-26%2015.53.59.png?dl=0

Perfect alignment, Google Maps API map visible...

---

How to fix this? Anyone knows? I have added web-prefixes for flex, and that solved some issues. But the ones above, I do not know how to fix!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276